# When sorting an array of objects, is it possible to further group items that have been pushed to the top, using sort()?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a sort function that sorts a list by name but I want every item that starts with an underscore to be grouped at the top.
I need to force underscores to the top when sorting in a descending order (Z-A). So using a normal localeCompare won't work as it would put underscores at the bottom.
For item names that start with an underscore I push to the top using:

```
if(item1.name().indexOf("_") == 0){
    res = -1
}
if(item2.name().indexOf("_") == 0){
    res = 1
}
```

The problem with this is that all those items are all together at the top but they're all jumbled up and what I need is for them to be further sorted by name i.e. so that it's sorted by the letters that come after the underscore.

I also need to do this purely as a single sort function.

Comment: Only return the `-1` or `1` if the other item does not start with `_`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could check the first character and move the ones with `'_'` to top and then sort descending.

```js
var array = ['_a', 'a', 'abc', '_d', 'ef'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b[0] === '_') - (a[0] === '_') || b.localeCompare(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't take into account the possibility that both items could start with the underscore. There are four possibilities:

```
if both start with "_", return result of comparing with localeCompare
if item1 starts with "_", it's less than item2
if item2 starts with "_", it's greater than item1
otherwise, neither starts with "_", so compare them with localeCompare
```

Or, in code:

```
if (item1.name().indexOf("_") == 0 && item2.name().indexOf("_") == 0)
    res = item1.name().localeCompare(item2.name());
else if (item1.name().indexOf("_") == 0
    res = -1;
else if (item2.name().indexOf("_") == 0
    res = 1;
else
    res = item1.name().localeCompare(item2.name());
```